# Llama.generate: prefix-match hit

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama

I am using "llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin" (from hugging-face) using "LlamaCpp()" in langchain. The process of "Llama.generate: prefix-match hit" repeats itself so many times and answers itself. But I want answer only once. How can I set this to generate answer only once?

I am using LlamaCpp() to load the model and RetrievalQA to retrieval of answers.